# \ref should use enumerate label name

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, enumerate

I have done this:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\textbf{S.\theenumi}}
\item a
\item \label{l} b
\item c. goto \ref{l}
\end{enumerate}
```

The `\ref` just uses the enumerate number. But I want it to be the full `enumerate` label.

I also could just type `S.\ref{l}` but that has the two disadvantages that

1. if I update the enumerate label, I also have to update this reference,
2. together with `hyperref`, this doesn't look so nice.

How would be a clean/nice way to solve this?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You can use the [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{S.\arabic*}]
\item a
\item \label{l} b
\item c. goto \ref{l}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{S.\arabic*},ref=S.\arabic*]
\item a
\item \label{l} b
\item c. goto \ref{l}
\end{enumerate}
```

if you don't want the reference to be boldfaced.

Comment: This is nice. I would like to add that it does not work together with \usepackage{paralist} ... if you need to use that package.

Comment: I'm curius, what does the * after \arabic stands for?

Comment: @GillesBonnet The * automatically picks the correct counter, such as enumi or enumii depending on the level of nesting.

Answer (score 22):

For your attempt properly work, you need redefine the counter representation (`\theenumi`) as well as the label associated with it (`\labelenumi`). This separates the formatting from the counter when you're using `\ref`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\textbf{\theenumi}}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{S.\arabic{enumi}}
\item a
\makeatletter
\show\@currentlabel
\makeatother
\item \label{l} b
\item c. goto \ref{l}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

This also works nicely with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). However, in general, it is much easier to use [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) since it can be used in a global *or* localized setting using a key-value approach; very convenient.

Answer (score 1):

For all counters in LaTeX (not needing packages) there is a macro \p@*counter* used as a prefix in label/ref for that counter. So the matching set of definitions would be

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\textbf{\theenumi}}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{S.\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\p@enumi}{S.}
\makeatother
```

The more natural way of doing it would be to leave \theenumi as just the counter value, and put all adornment in the others

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\textbf{S.\theenumi}}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\p@enumi}{S.}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 0):

With packages paralist works as well

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\usepackage{paralist}
\begin{enumerate}[\bfseries{S}.1]
\item a
\makeatletter
\show\@currentlabel
\makeatother
\item \label{l} b
\item c. goto \ref{l}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```