# write mathematical condition environment

Tags: math-mode, environments

I want to have numbering for mathematical condition but I can't find any environment for this. I mean something like this:

```
\begin{condition}
    a should be posotive
\end{condition}
\begin{condition}
    b should be Negative
\end{condition}
```

and have this output:

```
condition 1.1: a should be positive
condition 1.2: b should be Negative
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "but I can't find any space for this"?.

Comment: I edited my question; please take a look. thanks. @CroCo

Comment: Your question is not clear can you add a MWE

Comment: Is an `itemize` (or similar) with customized item label not enough?

Comment: @SalimBou I edited my question, Of course problem solved :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thanks man! You saved me! I didn't know that `code` ans `code` can have customed labels I used  [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58713/ref-should-use-enumerate-label-name)  answer and then I made that. Thanks again.

Comment: @SalehSalehizadeh You are welcome, but I'm a woman :)

Comment: A question, though: will you have other series of conditions, that should be numbered continuously?

Comment: @Bernard In my case there was only one series of conditions. Generally You right!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve something like this with the `\newtheorem` command, which is part of LaTeX. If you want to have more flexibility (e.g. for adjusting the font chosen for the label and the text), load the `amsthm` package in the preamble. The advantage of viewing your conditions as 'theorems' is that you can use the `\label` and the `\ref` command to refer to the conditions later on. For more information on the command `\newtheorem` see [WikiBooks: LaTeX/Theorems](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Theorems).

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{condition}{Condition}[section]
\begin{document}
\section{My conditions}
\begin{condition}\label{cond for a}
  $a$ should be positive.
\end{condition}
\begin{condition}\label{cond for b}
  $b$ should be negative.
\end{condition}
Note that condition~\ref{cond for a} implies condition~\ref{cond for b}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In my next project I'll use this! You learned my a valuable command :) thanks :)

Comment: In a serious text I recommend writing "Condition 1.1 implies Condition 1.2'', since they are proper names.