# Links to items in the list do not appear

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, enumitem, links

I am using my own list-like environment and have problems referencing items in it. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcounter{qcounter}

\newenvironment{questions}{
    \begin{list}{ 
        }{
            \renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{%
                \textbf{\refstepcounter{qcounter}\arabic{qcounter}.##1}
            }%
        } 
    }{ 
    \end{list}
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{questions}

        \item \lipsum[2] \label{one}

        \item Here should be a clickable link to item number one~\ref{one} and four~\ref{four}.

        \item[${}^{*}$] \label{three}

        \item[\textsubscript{four}] \label{four} And here is link to number tree~\ref{three}.

    \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

The references do not appear in the text:

[image]

How can I make clickable links without using the standart `enumerate` (I would like to keep the functionality of my own list)?

Comment: Does [\ref should use enumerate label name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58714/124842) help?

Comment: @Bobyandbob no, can't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears `\makelabel` is used inside a group, and `\@currentlabel` is local to that group.  Fortunately, `\@currentHref` is already global.

Some of the charges are gratuitous, but I was copying the definition of `description` from article.cls.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}% not used here
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcounter{qcounter}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\questionlabel[1]{\refstepcounter{qcounter}%
  \global\let\@currentlabel=\@currentlabel
  \normalfont\bfseries \arabic{qcounter}.#1}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{questions}{%
    \list{}{\let\makelabel=\questionlabel}%
  }{\endlist}

\begin{document}

    \begin{questions}

        \item \lipsum[2] \label{one} (\csname @currentlabel\endcsname)

        \item Here should be a clickable link to item number one~\ref{one} and four~\ref{four}.

        \item[${}^{*}$] \label{three}

        \item[\textsubscript{four}] \label{four} And here is link to number tree~\ref{three}.

    \end{questions}

\end{document}
```