# Customize reference in newenvironment

Tags: cross-referencing, environments, lists, enumerate

One of my professors in CS have made us use his template to write our master thesis in Software Engineering.

When I use \ref{...} it only appears the number, which is a problem because I have multiple subsystems and each one has their own list (eg. one is SGPA1 and other is SGU1).
I've been trying to change it using this question ([\ref should use enumerate label name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58713/ref-should-use-enumerate-label-name)), and it hasn't worked.

Is there any solution so when I use \ref{*an item of the environment*} it also shows the characters (SGPA in this example)?

```
\newenvironment{functionalProcesosAutomaticos}
{
    \bgroup
    \renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.3}
  \typeout{Begining enumeration}
  \ifnum
    \@enumdepth >3 \@toodeep
  \else
    \advance\@enumdepth \@ne
    \def\@enumctr{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}
    \list{\csname label\@enumctr\endcsname}
    {
            \small
      \partopsep=0\myem 
      \topsep=\@listinterlined 
      \itemsep=\@listinterlined 
      \parsep=\@listinterlined 
      \advance\topsep by .3\myem
      \advance\itemsep by .15\myem
      \itemindent=0\myem
      \rightmargin=5\myex
      \leftmargin=8\myex
      \labelsep=1\myex \labelwidth=3\myex
      \usecounter{\@enumctr}
      \renewcommand*{\labelenumi}{\textbf{SGPA\theenumi}}
      \renewcommand*{\theenumii}{\arabic{enumii}}
      \renewcommand*{\labelenumii}{\textbf{SGPA\theenumi.\theenumii.--}}
      \renewcommand*{\theenumiii}{\arabic{enumiii}}
      \renewcommand*{\labelenumiii}{\textbf{SGPA\theenumi.\theenumii.\theenumiii.--}}
    }
  \fi
}
{
                \endlist
        \typeout{Ending enumeration}
        \egroup
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You adjusted
`\theenumi`, `\theenumii`, `\theenumiii`
and
`\labelenumi`, `\labelenumii`, `\labelenumiii`.

I think you need to also adjust
`\p@enumi`, `\p@enumii`, `\p@enumiii`.

These macros deliver prefix/postfix to `\the⟨counter⟩` when `\refstepcounter` stores cross-referencing-data used by `\label` as  macro `\@currentlabel`.

I don't know what `\myem`, `\myex` and `\@listinterlined` are, but I assume they are some units/lengths and I defined them on my own, with weird values. ;-)

Does the example deliver the output you desire?

```latex
\errorcontextlines=10000

\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter

\def\myem{em}
\def\myex{ex}
\def\@listinterlined{.5\baselineskip}

\newenvironment{functionalProcesosAutomaticos}
{%%%%
    \bgroup
    \renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.3}%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \typeout{Begining enumeration}%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \advance\@enumdepth \@ne
  \ifnum
    \@enumdepth >4 \@toodeep
  \else
    \def\@enumctr{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}%%%%
    \list{\csname label\@enumctr\endcsname}%%%%
    {%%%%
            \small
      \partopsep=0\myem\relax
      \topsep=\@listinterlined\relax
      \itemsep=\@listinterlined\relax
      \parsep=\@listinterlined\relax
      \advance\topsep by .3\myem\relax
      \advance\itemsep by .15\myem\relax
      \itemindent=0\myem\relax
      \rightmargin=5\myex\relax
      \leftmargin=8\myex\relax
      \labelsep=1\myex\relax
      \labelwidth=3\myex\relax
      \usecounter{\@enumctr}%
      \renewcommand*{\theenumi}{SGPA\arabic{enumi}}%%%%
      \renewcommand*{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}}%%%%
      \renewcommand*{\theenumiii}{\theenumii.\arabic{enumiii}}%%%%
      \renewcommand*{\theenumiv}{\theenumiii.\arabic{enumiv}}%%%%
      \renewcommand*{\p@enumi}{}%%%%
      \renewcommand*{\p@enumii}{}%%%%
      \renewcommand*{\p@enumiii}{}%%%%
      \renewcommand*{\p@enumiv}{}%%%%
%      \renewcommand*{\p@enumii}[1]{##1.--}%%%%
%      \renewcommand*{\p@enumiii}[1]{##1.--}%%%%
%      \renewcommand*{\p@enumiv}[1]{##1.--}%%%%
      \renewcommand*{\labelenumi}{\textbf{\theenumi}}%%%%
      \renewcommand*{\labelenumii}{\textbf{\theenumii}}%%%%
      \renewcommand*{\labelenumiii}{\textbf{\theenumiii}}%%%%
      \renewcommand*{\labelenumiv}{\textbf{\theenumiv}}%%%%
%      \renewcommand*{\labelenumii}{\textbf{\theenumii.--}}%%%%
%      \renewcommand*{\labelenumiii}{\textbf{\theenumiii.--}}%%%%
%      \renewcommand*{\labelenumiv}{\textbf{\theenumiv.--}}%%%%
    }%%%%
  \fi
}{%%%%
        \ifnum
          \@enumdepth >4 
        \else
          \expandafter\endlist
        \fi
        \typeout{Ending enumeration}%%%%
        \egroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ref{AnotherItem}

\ref{AnotherNestedItem}

\ref{AnotherNestedNestedItem}

\ref{AnotherNestedNestedNestedItem}

\begin{functionalProcesosAutomaticos}
\item An item
\item\label{AnotherItem} Another item
\item Yet another item
\begin{functionalProcesosAutomaticos}
\item A nested item
\item\label{AnotherNestedItem} Another nested item
\item Yet another nested item
\begin{functionalProcesosAutomaticos}
\item A nested nested item
\item\label{AnotherNestedNestedItem} Another nested nested item
\item Yet another nested nested item
\begin{functionalProcesosAutomaticos}
\item A nested nested nested item
\item\label{AnotherNestedNestedNestedItem} Another nested nested nested item
\item Yet another nested nested nested item
%\begin{functionalProcesosAutomaticos}
%\item A nested nested nested nested item
%\item\label{AnotherNestedNestedNestedNestedItem} Another nested nested nested nested item
%\item Yet another nested nested nested nested item
%\end{functionalProcesosAutomaticos}
\end{functionalProcesosAutomaticos}
\end{functionalProcesosAutomaticos}
\end{functionalProcesosAutomaticos}
\end{functionalProcesosAutomaticos}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ```\def\listinterlined#1{\def\@listinterlined{#1}}
\listinterlined{0.1\myem}``` is the list interlined, and yes, it is what I'm looking for but it doesn't work in my template :/
It doesn't compile the document, so I think at this point is a template issue, thank you anyway

Comment: I honestly can't. The template is an absolute mess and when I tried to copy paste your code it just explode. It says _No PDF, something went wrong_ , and no matter how many times I try to recompile it's always the same. Thank you so much for your effort, I really appreciate it :-)

Comment: My bad!! I have just tried it again and it worked!!! I may have copied it wrongly or something. Thank you so so much

Comment: You're the best, I swear this was driving me insane

Comment: @SugarG.García I know these situations: Time pressure, you want to get the job done, and then you find yourself spending hours trying to trace what's going wrong... In between, you get bile up, because you actually have something better to do... :-)