How to Ensure Period Appears in LaTeX List but Not in References, While Keeping Hyperref on the Entire Label?
I have created custom enumerated lists in LaTeX using the enumitem package, and I want the period to appear in the list but not in the references when using \ref or \cref. Additionally, I want the entire label (e.g., “RQ1”) to be hyperlinked when using \ref or \cref, not just the number.
Here is how I defined my lists:
\newlist{study}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[study]{label=\textbf{Study \arabic*.},leftmargin=0pt,itemindent=*, itemsep=7pt}
\crefname{studyi}{S}{S}

\newlist{resq}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[resq]{label=\textbf{RQ\arabic*.},leftmargin=0pt,itemindent=*, itemsep=3pt}

And here’s how I use them with labels:
\begin{resq}
  \item\label{rq1} This is the first research questions?
  \item\label{rq2} I guess this is the second one?
\end{resq}

When I reference these items in my document, I use:
To address \ref{rq:nlra}, we conducted...

The problem is that \ref outputs the label with a period (e.g., “RQ1.”) instead of just “RQ1” (naturally because I have defined it in the custom list). I want the period to appear in the list but not in the references. Also, I want the entire “RQ1” (not just the number “1”) to be hyperlinked when referenced in the text.
How can I achieve this formatting?

enumitem has separate keys for the label in the item and the label as reference, called label= and ref=. So in your case \setlist[resq]{label=\textbf{RQ\arabic*.},ref=\textbf{RQ\arabic*}. The question is a duplicate, let me see if I can find a previous one to close this.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58713/ref-should-use-enumerate-label-name explains it quite well for example.

But \ref should use enumerate label name is a bit simpler, maybe that is a better duplicate candidate.

OMG, thank you very much. I don't know why I could not find it at all anywhere I searched :/ This is definitely correct and worked. Please refer to the other question if you find it.

@Marijn is it better to delete my question when it is flagged as duplicate or to keep it as reference if anyone finds this question?

You can keep it around, the idea of duplicate closure is indeed that a new question could help future visitors that may not have found the older questions (like you) in case they do find this question for some reason (because it is formulated in a different way, even if it is essentially the same question).
